# Error: invalid initialization of type

Tags: c++

```
istream& operator>> (istream &in, vector <Customer>& cvect)
{
    while (!in.eof())
    {
         //read from file into cvect vector
    }
    return cvect;
}
```

For this i get "invalid initialization of reference of type cvect". What am i doing wrong?

Comment: So you want to return a vector as an istream?

Comment: No, i just wanna make changes to the Customer vector. thats all

Comment: s/return cvect/return in

Comment: That's not the whole error message. I'd bet it further says "with an rvalue of type Vector<Customer>". You can't bind non-const references to temporaries.

Comment: [`while (!eof())` is wrong.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong)

Answer (score 6):

Your function says it will return a `istream` reference:

```
istream& operator>> (istream &in, vector <Customer>& cvect)
```

Your compiler believes you.
You then say

```
return cvect;
```

This is not an istream, it's a vector.
Try returning the istream as you promised you would:

```
return in;
```